# cygwin / vista32 bash.exe has stopped working

Tags: cygwin, windows-vista, exit

Our work machines are moving to Vista, so I am struggling through installing cygwin.
After setting the proxy on the installer manually instead of using "use IE5 settings" and running the following command:

```
mkpasswd -l -c > /etc/passwd; mkgroup -l -d > /etc/group
```

I finally have a "working" version of cygwin.

However, when I type exit to kill the shell, vista gives me the lovely message box of "bash.exe has stopped working" and it goes through trying to figure out what went wrong.  You can either "cancel" the progress or wait until it quits trying and "close program".

Is there a workaround for this?  Insight into why it is occurring?  Perhaps there is a windows way to stop all notification of this type of behavior - or there is a way to get cygwin to quit "gracefully-as-defined-by-MS"?

Comment: this doesn't seem too programming-related.  it would be much more appropriate on the cygwin at cygwin dot com mailing list.

Comment: Cygwin is often used to use GCC/GDB/etc. on Windows. I think the question should be allowed.

Comment: There is a cygwin tag on this site for a reason.  I'm assuming others see this as a *necessary* tool for programming when "stuck" on windows.  I try my best not to flood mailing lists with common questions.  I first web search, post on a forum (or this site), THEN resort to mailing lists.  Admins correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I run Cygwin on Vista without any problem. I didn't do any special configuration. I simply installed it.

Try to set the Cygwin Bash shortcut to execute with admin permissions.  (Though, I didn't need to do this)

Also, which version of Vista are you using? I set my copy up on Vista Ultimate; I'm not sure if this would make a difference.  Also, which version of Cygwin did you install and where did you install it to? (Which path?)

**Update** based on answers:
I'm not sure but I'd bet you the problem is that it is installed in /Program Files/ folder. Vista probably considers that a protected folder.  May I suggest that you install it to either `C:\Cygwin` or, at the least, your Documents (or that area) folder.  You should also avoid spaces in your path. I don't know what you are using it for, but some make files will fail if there are spaces (according to what I understand).

I'm by no means an expert.

Comment: Sorry for "20 questions". :-)

Comment: We run vista business at work.  The way UAC and security is setup at work, installing things to C: can be a hassle.  I created a directory off of c called "myc" and gave myself full permissions.  Now I DID install it to C:\myc\Program Files\cygwin - which was cautioned against by the installer as there is a space in "Program Files" but I felt this was a m00t point and it should be handled gracefully and went on my merry way.  If this is the issue I will be more sad than happy.

FWIW - running as admin has same behavior

Comment: oops, only answered 19 of them ;)
$ uname -srv
CYGWIN_NT-6.0 1.5.25(0.156/4/2) 2008-06-12 19:34